# Drupal commerce Attributes with skus, Product Bundles

Tags: drupal, bundle, commerce

I am creating a Drupal Commerce site. Need products with 3 different sets of options, each with a unique price and it's own sku, which changes from product to product. I got it to work somewhat by using customizable products, but got no sku, need a sku for the options. Then tried product bundle, but can't get that to work at all, fairly new to Drupal. Anyone know how to add a sku to a customizable product? Or make product bundles actually work? What are the steps, can't find decent instructions on the product bundle. Josh Miller has a video on customizable products (pizza toppings), that's how I got those to work, gosh, just need a sku for each item. Please help, seriously behind project. Thinking of changing to Ubercart, which I have never used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up on how the drupal commerce module works. Basically drupal commerce supplies a product entity type, these products are not visible on the site. You have to create your own 'product display' node type which has a 'product reference' field type. When you edit the 'product display' you will then choose (by selecting in the product reference field) which products are to be displayed on this product display. Each 'product option' has it's own unique product (and sku). There are a multitude of tutorials on the net that run you through the process. http://bit.ly/W6CoWI